# How to move 3D object by pixels in opengl

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I have a 3d model in the front and in the background an image.  I am trying to move the 3d model (x, y) by pixels. But the `glTranslatef` func move it in some other metrics.
 I try `glViewport(0, 0, width, height)` and then `glOrtho(x, width, height, y, 0.0, 1.0)` but it make the object to
disappear.
 this is my code:

```
# draw the 3d model

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()

        glOrtho(0.0, width, height, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.1, 50.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        # reddering the 3d object
        box.render()
```

Comment: Why are you using glOrtho **and** gluPerspective?

Comment: I an not using glOrtho ths what  try and t makke the 3d to disappear. If i remove the gluPerspective the 3d never showup

Comment: I am new to opengl and I think I now what `gluPerspective` it do.

Comment: do you know that farther away things are smaller, so your movement is also smaller when the object is farther away?

Comment: Yes. but I want to move it by pixels. i wnat to now the relation between `glTranslatef` (x,,y) values and pixels values

Comment: The relationship is very complicated since it depends on things like the FOV. Later you may be able to understand it, but not at the level where gluPerspective is a magic incantation.

Comment: Do you know any good source to read about it.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you'd probably want to get the current MV and P matrices, multiply them together and invert the result. Or you could move the whole screen by pixels, by translating at the very first step of the projection matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This answer extends the last comment by @user253751 in the question above:

Yes, you will need the the three matrices, `Model, View and Projection` to transform your objects from local space to `screen coordinates` (pixel space).

OpenGL Transformation generally occur like this:

`World space //Model Matrix`  --> `View Space //View Matrix`  --> `NDC Coordinates (Clip Space) //Projection Matrix` -->
`Screen Coordinates` //OpenGL does this automatically

So to go from screen coordinates (pixel coords) you just apply the inverse of those Matrices.

Say for example you have and object in screen coordinates at `(100, 100)`, and you want to move it to `(300, 300)`.

Find the world space coordinates (x, y, z) by the reverting the coordinate `(300, 300)` to 3D world space by the inverse view and projection, and transform your objects position there. (**This is also known as ray-casting**)

Without the MVP system setup, it will be very hard for you to move objects via pixels.

Here is a [good tutorial by LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) on `space` and `coordinates` in OpenGL.